# How do I find maximum degree of a vertex in $G$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Common Data for Questions $1, 2, 3:$

The $2^n$  vertices of a graph $G$ corresponds to all subsets of a set of size $n$, for $n≥6$.  Two vertices of $G$ are adjacent if and only if the corresponding sets intersect in exactly two elements.

Q.1. The number of vertices of degree zero in $G$ is:

1. $1$
2. $n$
3. $n + 1$
4. $2^n$

---

Q.2.The maximum degree of a vertex in $G$ is:

1. $^{n/2}C_2.2^{n/2}$
2. $2^{n−2}$
3. $2^{n−3}×3$
4. $2^{n−1}$

---

Q.3. The number of connected components in $G$ is:

1. $n$
2. $n+2$
3. $2^{n/2}$
4. $\frac{2^n}{n}$

---

#### My Try:

Given there set size is $n$ where $n\geq6$. Number of vertices is $2^n$ of graph $G$.

Note that power of $n$ elements, i.e. $2^n$ elements in powerset of $n$ elements where $1$-element of size is $0$ i.e $\phi$.

$n$-element of size is $1$ i.e $\{1\} ,\{2\} ,\{3\},....,\{n\}$.

Similarly size of $k$, total number of elements are $^nC_k$.

Now,

Two vertices of $G$ are adjacent if and only if the corresponding sets intersect in exactly two elements.

Note that $1$-element of size is $0$ i.e $\phi$ and

$n$-element of size is $1$ i.e $\{1\} ,\{2\} ,\{3\},....,\{n\}$ have less than two elements that can not be connected to any other vertices due to less number of elements in that sets, Total such element are$ = 1 + n$ and remaining (i.e. $2^n - (n+1)$) are connected, since these have more than one elements in that sets.

So, total number of connected components in $G$ is$ = (n+1)$ disconnected $+1$((i.e. $2^n - (n+1)$)remaining  are connected)$ = n + 2$.

---

I'm not getting Q.2.

> Can you explain little bit please, how do I find maximum degree of a vertex in $G$?

Somewhere, it explained and answer is given $(^kC_2.2^{(n-k)}) =  ^3C_2 . 2^{(n-3)} = 3.2^{(n-3)}$.

Comment: Is there a typo? How can you get two subsets of size two that have size of intersection 2? Or does the graph admit loops?

Comment: Should it say intersect in exactly one element?

Comment: For number two try using AM-GM

Comment: @dREaM, AFAIK : there is no typo.

Comment: Can you explain in steps with detail for each node, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the vertices that a subset of size $k$ is connected to, you choose two of the elements to be the intersection, then can choose any of the $n-k$.  There are $k \choose 2$ ways to do the first and $2^{n-k}$ of the second.  As long as $k \gt 2$ this will not be the same subset.  You are trying to find the $k$ that maximizes the product. Adding one to $k$ will multiply the first term by $\frac {k+1}{k-1}$ and divide the second term by $2$, so you break even at $k=3$

Added:  The degree of a vertex is the number of other subsets that it intersects in exactly two elements.  For an example, let $k=5, n=12$.  The subset might as well be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ out of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$.  How many other subsets intersect in exactly two elements?  We have to choose two elements for the intersection out of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, which we can do in ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways.  We can then have any or all of $\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$, which has $2^7=128$ subsets.  In total, a five element subset has ${5 \choose 2}2^7=1280$ other subsets it is connected with.  Similarly, for $k \gt 2$, a $k$-element subset is connected to ${k \choose 2}2^{n-k}=\frac 12k(k-1)2^{n-k}$ other subsets.  For $k=2$, we have to subtract one because if the subset of the $n-2$ elements we pick is empty we have the same set as we started with.  We are asked to find the $k$ that maximizes this.  We find $$\begin {array} {c |c} k&\text {sets}\\ \hline2&2\cdot2^{n-2}-1\\3&3\cdot 2^{n-3}\\4&6\cdot 2^{n-4}\\5&10\cdot 2^{n-5} \end {array}$$ which is maximum at $k=3$ and $k=4$

Comment: How $k=3$ maximize the product?

Comment: I am taking the ratio of the results for $k$ and $k+1$.  Either $k=3$ or $k=4$ will maximize the product-it is the same in both cases.  With $k=3$ you have three ways to select the intersection with another subset and $2^{n-3}$ ways to select the other elements.  With $k=4$ you have six ways to select the intersection and $2^{n-4}$ ways to select the other elements.

Comment: Can you expand answer  for each node, please?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
you can compute the degree of a vertex of size $m$ as follow:

1. first choose 2 elements among the $m$ to be the one that will make the conection
2. then choose elements to complete the sets that you will be connected to. you can complete the sets with any number of elements from the $n-m$ elements left.

Once you get the formula for the degree of a vertex of size $m$ you have to find the maximum. I would proceed by derivation (I didn't do it but I think it would give you the expected result). Note that there may be a cleverer  way to get the maximum ...

I hope it helps